# redux-observable + socket.io: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm playing around with redux-observable and socket.io and trying to verify token by socket.emits, but redux-observable says that thing about actions. Then I tried to use switchMaps, but I've got only last dispatch in methods list. I tried different operators and methods, but it didnt work too. Where could I be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code. At first we're emitting token (in example it's `suc`, like success), on the server if token is `===` to `suc` I send emit with `verifySuccess`, otherwise `verifyError`. I've tested server side in case like maybe problem is there, but it's not.

Front

```
export default function verify(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(TOKEN_VERIFY_REQUEST)
    .map(action => Observable.of(socket.emit('verify', { token: 'suc' })))
    .mapTo(
      Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'verifySuccess')
        .mapTo({ type: TOKEN_VERIFY_SUCCESS })
    )
    .mapTo(
      Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'verifyError')
        .mapTo({ type: TOKEN_VERIFY_FAILURE })
    )
}
```

Back

```
socket.on('verify', async (data) => {
      console.log(`got verify with`.red)
      console.log(data)
      const msgs = {
        suc: { msg: 'Received data' },
        err: { msg: 'Error in request' }
      }
      console.log(`data.token is ${data.token}`)
      if (data.token === 'suc') {
        console.log(`sending success`)
        socket.emit('verifySuccess', msgs.suc)
      } else {
        console.log(`sending error`)
        socket.emit('verifyError', msgs.err)
      }
     })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some fundamental misunderstandings about RxJS, so I would spend some time to really get a solid foundation on it or consider using something like redux-thunk instead if your async needs aren't more complex than this.

So here are some things to guide you:

- Your `map` is returning an Observable, which means you now have an Observable of Observables aka `Observable<Observable>` which is almost certainly not what you want.
- It's not clear what `Observable.of(socket.emit('verify', { token: 'suc' })))` is meant to do because `socket.emit()` returns the socket itself, so you're emitting then mapping the action to an Observable of the Socket itself?
- The `mapTo` usages are also probably not what you intend. The second one cancels the first, and again you're creating an Observable of Observable. So your epic is emitting (and hence dispatching) a stream of Observables, not actions, which is why you get the "actions must be plain objects" error from redux.

I'm hesitant to give you a solution, but I'll ask that you try to truly understand it rather than just copy-pasting. Maybe take a step back, try to forget all your current beliefs on how Rx works and start fresh? You then might have that "ah ha!" moment :)

I'm guessing you meant to do something like this:

```
export default function tokenVerifyRequestEpic(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(TOKEN_VERIFY_REQUEST)
    .do(() => {
      socket.emit('verify', { token: 'suc' }));
    })
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.race(
        Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'verifySuccess')
          .mapTo({ type: TOKEN_VERIFY_SUCCESS }),
        Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'verifyError')
          .mapTo({ type: TOKEN_VERIFY_FAILURE })
      )
    );
}
```

Here it is with verbose inline comments:

```
export default function tokenVerifyRequestEpic(action$) {
  // filter out all actions except TOKEN_VERIFY_REQUEST
  return action$.ofType(TOKEN_VERIFY_REQUEST)
    // perform the side effect of emitting the 'verify' message
    .do(() => {
      socket.emit('verify', { token: 'suc' }));
    })
    // One problem with this code is that it might not properly account for
    // multiple concurrent TOKEN_VERIFY_REQUEST requests. e.g. How are those
    // handled by the server? How should be they be handled in the UI?
    // If it's not supposed to be possible, it might be useful to assert
    // against that condition so that if it does accidentally happen you
    // throw an error
    .mergeMap(() =>
      // Race between either a 'verifySuccess' or 'verifyError'
      // This assumes one or the other will always happen, if not
      // then you might want to add a timeout() or similar
      Observable.race(
        Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'verifySuccess')
          .mapTo({ type: TOKEN_VERIFY_SUCCESS }),
        Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'verifyError')
          .mapTo({ type: TOKEN_VERIFY_FAILURE })
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as I wanted it to work. Can you show an example how to add timeout?